# screenshot is not saved to clipboard

Tags: screenshot

To save the area to the clipboard, I have the default key combination Shift+Ctrl+Printscreen. Then I cut the area, but there is nothing in the clipboard (check via Ctrl+V). It happened a week ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid we broke that in the last Gala release when we tried to remove a lag / freeze when making screenshots (See: [PR](https://github.com/elementary/gala/pull/460)).
We've solved the issue and it should be fixed with the next release of Gala.

Issue: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/474
Fix: https://github.com/elementary/gala/pull/481

**Update:** A new version of Gala was released which should include the fix:
Version: `0.3.2~r690+pkg45~ubuntu5.0.1`
On: 2019-03-05

Comment: Hi. I still have this issue with 0.3.2~r698+pkg45~ubuntu5.0.1